# Translate shadertoy texture to webgl not behaving the same

Tags: glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I'm able to translate the code and run it, but it behaves diferrent from the orginal fork.

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llS3zc --orignal

https://editor.p5js.org/jorgeavav/sketches/i9cd4lE7H - translate

Here is the code:

```
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float time;
uniform float mouse;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D texture2;



void main() {

    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
    vec4 texCol = vec4(texture2D(texture, uv+time/10.0));
    mat3 tfm;
    tfm[0] = vec3(texCol.z,0.0,0);
    tfm[1] = vec3(0.0,texCol.y,0);
    tfm[2] = vec3(0,0,1.0);    
    vec2 muv = (vec3(uv,1.0)*tfm).xy - 0.1*time;
    texCol = vec4(texture2D(texture2, muv));
    gl_FragColor = texCol;
```

}

Comment: It's probably a good idea to put the error you are getting in your question. I am guessing its "texture3d" and "gl.texture" that are the problem. They should probably both be "texture2d"

Comment: Hi thanks, is running but is not behaving the same.  I will update my question and place the links.

Comment: I edited can you give it a look when you have time please?

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

1. Your textures are a lot larger than the shader toy ones, either use smaller textures or scale down the uv coordinates (`uv*=0.1` results in a similar scale).
2. Your textures are not wrapping and their dimensions are not a power of two(which is required to enable wrapping [in WebGL1]), you need to resize the textures and apply wrapping using `textureWrap(REPEAT)` or wrap in the shader, for example by using `fract` to wrap the lookup coordinates in your `texture2D` calls.

Comment: hey! thanks go it. Just in the second part i will prefer to do it in the webgl side, but not sure how to wrap the lookups can you give me a hint ? thanks.

Comment: also how i get the textures at power of two?

Comment: thanks! getting there i thinks i was able to do what you respones, but still  working  abit diferent i update the p5.js llink